# Neural network as alternative to conventional nonlinear regression?

Tags: regression, neural-networks, nonlinear-regression

Can I use the strength of neural networks for data analysis? Suppose I want to find a fit to a noisy sine curve $1 - V \sin(w \theta+ \phi)$ and I want to find an estimate for parameters V, $w$ and $\phi$. Can such a parameter estimation be done using neural networks?

If it is helpful, I am aware that Pytorch can certainly do some kind of modeling of noisy sine curves, but this won't translate to parameters.

For example, the following Pytorch code uses a neural network to model a noisy sine curve:

```
import torch import torch.nn as nn import torch.optim as optim import numpy as np import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(0) x = np.sort(np.random.uniform(-np.pi, np.pi, 200)) V
= 0.3 real = 1 - V*np.cos(x) noise = np.random.normal(0, 0.1, real.shape) y = real + noise

x = x[:, np.newaxis] y = y[:, np.newaxis]

x_tensor = torch.tensor(x, dtype=torch.float32).flatten().unsqueeze(1) y_tensor = torch.tensor(y, dtype=torch.float32)

net = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Linear(in_features=1, out_features=200),
    nn.Tanh(),
    nn.Linear(in_features=200, out_features=1), )

criterion = nn.MSELoss() optimizer = optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.01)

epochs = 5000 for epoch in range(epochs):
    output = net(x_tensor)
    loss = criterion(output, y_tensor)
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    if (epoch+1) % 500 == 0:
        print('Epoch [{}/{}], Loss: {:.4f}'.format(epoch+1, epochs, loss.item()))

predicted = net(x_tensor).detach().numpy()

plt.plot(x, y, 'ro', label='Original data') plt.plot(x, predicted, label='Fitted line') plt.legend() plt.show()  print('visiblity found with value of: ', predicted)
```

EDIT:
As suggested in the comments, I have a new attempt at this. In this I generate a dataset of X,Y values associated with Y = 1-v Cos(wX+phi), for random values of (w, phi, and v). Then I try to train a neural network that has inputs (X,Y) and provides an output of (w, phi, and v), which is written as follows:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Parameters for generating the data
n_samples = 200
n_sets = 1000  # number of different sets of parameters

# Generating x values 
x_values = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, n_samples)
x_data = np.tile(x_values, (n_sets, 1)) # Repeat x_values for each set of parameters

V_values = np.random.uniform(0.1, 0.5, n_sets)
phi_values = np.random.uniform(-np.pi, np.pi, n_sets)
w_values = np.random.uniform(1, 5, n_sets)

# Generating y data based on the parameters 
y_data = []
targets = []
for V, phi, w in zip(V_values, phi_values, w_values):
    y = 1 - V * np.cos(w * x_values + phi)
    noise = np.random.normal(0, 0.1, y.shape)  
    y += noise
    y_data.append(y)
    targets.append([V, phi, w])

# Convert arrays to the tensor format
input_data_tensor = torch.tensor(np.concatenate((x_data, y_data), axis=1), dtype=torch.float32)
params_tensor = torch.tensor(targets, dtype=torch.float32)

class ParamNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ParamNet, self).__init__()
        self.layer1 = nn.Linear(2 * n_samples, 600)
        self.activ1 = nn.LeakyReLU()
        self.layer2 = nn.Linear(600, 600)  
        self.activ2 = nn.LeakyReLU()
        self.param_layer = nn.Linear(600, 3)  # Parameter output layer

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.activ1(self.layer1(x))
        x = self.activ2(self.layer2(x))
        params = self.param_layer(x)
        return params

model = ParamNet()

# Defining loss function and optimizer
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.1)
loss_fn = nn.MSELoss()

# Training loop
epochs = 5000
for epoch in range(epochs):
    params = model(input_data_tensor)
    loss = loss_fn(params, params_tensor)
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    if (epoch + 1) % 500 == 0:
        print(f"Epoch {epoch + 1}/{epochs}, Loss: {loss.item()}")

# Predicting parameters
predicted = model(input_data_tensor).detach().numpy()

# Evaluating model performance
mse = np.mean((predicted - targets)**2)
print("MSE: ", mse)


V_true = np.random.uniform(0.1, 0.5)
phi_true = np.random.uniform(-np.pi, np.pi)
w_true = np.random.uniform(1, 5)
y_new = 1 - V_true * np.cos(w_true * x_values + phi_true)
noise = np.random.normal(0, 0.1, y_new.shape)  # you can vary the amplitude of the noise
y_new += noise

# Prepare the tensor for model
x_values_tensor = torch.tensor(x_values, dtype=torch.float32).repeat(1, 1)  # repeat x_values for each set
y_new_tensor = torch.tensor(y_new, dtype=torch.float32).unsqueeze(0)  # unsqueeze to add one more dimension for batch
input_new_tensor = torch.cat((x_values_tensor, y_new_tensor), dim=-1)  # concatenate along the last dimension

# Pass the new data through the trained model
predicted_params = model(input_new_tensor).detach().numpy()[0]
V_pred, phi_pred, w_pred = predicted_params
y_pred = 1 - V_pred * np.cos(w_pred * x_values + phi_pred)

# Plot the original and predicted functions
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.plot(x_values, y_new, label='Original function')
plt.plot(x_values, y_pred, label='Predicted function', linestyle='--')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

It can sort of do it...but it get stuck at some local minima.

Comment: neural nets are most useful when you don't have a parametric form in mind; however you could try using a neural net to model the residual between the parametric part of the sinusoid and the observed data.

Comment: @JohnMadden, ah interesting, thanks.